Why do Kindle text file documents download and then immediately undownload?
I've tried to redeliver text documents, tried to resync, tried power cycling, but just cannot get some documents to download.
These are text files in notepad which I've e-mailed myself and show in documents.  Everything is plaintext.
What happens is that the file downloads...then the download dissapears.  With some files, if I time pressing the document to open the file it's possible to then read it on the Kindle.  However, I'm not able to do this consistently.
Is this a known problem where downloads immediately get undownloaded?  I couldn't find similar problems.  Some few files will download fine.  I've tried also "send to device" from the web library interface.
It's not a paperwhite, and is a few years old.  I don't have this problem with books from the Kindle store.
